# Call JavaScript val using window object & object key pair

Tags: javascript, global-variables, window-object

Okay, so I really would rather avoid using `eval` at all costs, so I'm trying to figure out an alternative to calling a global function using the window object method:

```
var time = new Date();
var varname = time.getDay();

var obj = {'eleID':'varname'};
for (var key in obj) {
    var vn = obj[key];
    eval(vn); //this works
    window[vn]; //this doesnt work
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've named the function object, now call it:

```
window[vn]();
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the variable I'm trying to get is just a string and not a function, so `window[vn]();` doesn't work.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII then `window[vn]` must work.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII dunno, some local JSFiddle issue: the current scope is not global. Assign the string to `window.varname` explicitly, or don't use `var`, it will set the variable globally. http://jsfiddle.net/faV5a/1/

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII check if the scope where you assign `varname` is the global one.

Comment: that was just so I don’t have to use `window[obj[key]];` but that doesnt work either...

Comment: I don't understand what doesn't work. The fiddle I provided does work.

Comment: Yeah, your update to it seemed to work... but even if I use the `winnow.` prefix when defining `varname` in my code it doesn't change.

Comment: I think I may just have to use eval. Nothing in that interacts with this code is user-defined, so it should be safe right?

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII post your code to JSFiddle so that I can look.

Comment: uhh… ALL of my code? It’s a couple thousand lines, and will break in JSfiddle because it won’t have access to all of the resources it needs. :P

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII no, the only part that makes troubles.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII `obj[str]` operation returns the child object of `obj` with name `str`. If you have `obj.foo.bar`, you cannot address `bar` with `obj["foo.bar"]`, because it will try to return an object with name `"foo.bar"`, while you want to get an object with name `"foo"`, and then its child `"bar"`.